# Excel VBA - Combo If statement

Tags: excel

i was curious what the vba would be to get a combo box to have two possible options :

- SSOBB --------->(= 2.4)
- SSTCB --------->(= 3.2)

[image]

When beam type is selected the count will divide the length by the beam type.

as the combo will contain only words and not the numerical value. im stuck how i will make the calculation.

Comment: Could you not combine `INDEX` and `MATCH` in a formula to get the value that goes with your text strings?

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(E3="SSCBB",(H3/2.4),IF(E3="SSTCB",(H3/3.2),""))
```

This method seemed to work. just declaring through data validation list boxes and this IF.

Answer (score 0):

Personaly i'am not sure why you searching for VBA solution but putting this formula to "count will be much better solution in my opinion :

=if(A2="SSOBB";B2/2,4;if(A2="SSTCB";B2/2,4;"Nothing to calculate"))

*=if( [your combobox]="Beam type";[your cell with length] / [value you want to divide with]; [ now add another if how many times you need ]; [and in the ind just value you want to show if nothing match]))

i hope i helped